# Creating arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm having difficulty understanding how arrays work in the Mongo shell.  It seems that whenever I create an array the "typeof" is still object and I when I try to run the following:

```
db.collection.find(test: {$type : 4})
```

I get no results, even though previously I had inserted an array into the collection using the following:

```
db.collection.insert({"test" : ["1", "2","3]})
```

Is this something I am not understanding about JSON or BSON? Are arrays still objects and if so how do you test if the object you have is an array? Ultimately I am hoping to split some strings in my database into arrays of strings but when I tested the type afterwards to ensure my code was working I was confused to find no type = array, even though they appear to be there when I look at `findOne()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**docs**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#arrays):

> When applied to arrays, $type matches any inner element that is of the
>   specified type. Without projection this means that the entire array
>   will match if any element has the right type. With projection, the
>   results will include just those elements of the requested type.

So your query:

```
db.collection.find({test: {$type : 4}})
```

will not match any documents because your field `test` is an array whose elements are strings. What you need is essentially

```
db.collection.find({ $where : "Array.isArray(this.test)" })
```

which will use [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) to list all documents containing a `test` field that is an array.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to test for an array type that doesn't use `$where` is to query for the existence of a first element, or for an empty array:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "a" : [] })
> db.test.insert({ "a" : 4 })
> db.test.insert({ "a" : [4] })
> db.test.find({ "$or" : [{ "a" : [] }, { "a.0" : { "$exists" : true } }] }, { "_id" : 0 })
{ "a" : [ ] }
{ "a" : [ 4 ] }
```

Comment: Thanks @wdberkeley this is also something I'll use in future